# Why not working: RelayCommand RaiseCanExecuteChanged

Tags: mvvm-light, relaycommand

When I call the `PressCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` in the `TimerOnElapsed` method, nothing happened.

What could be the problem?
(GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4 v4.0.30319 and GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4 v4.0.30319)

Here is my test code:

```
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

namespace CommandTest {


public class MainWindowVM : ViewModelBase {

    public MainWindowVM() {

        PressCommand = new RelayCommand(
                            () => MessageBox.Show("Pressed"),
                            () => _canExecute);

        PressCommand.CanExecuteChanged += (sender, args) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " CanExecuteChanged");

        _timer = new Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public RelayCommand PressCommand { get; private set; }

    #region Private

    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs) {
        _canExecute = !_canExecute;
        PressCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("At {0} enabled: {1}", elapsedEventArgs.SignalTime.ToLongTimeString(), _canExecute);
    }

    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private bool _canExecute;

    #endregion


}
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explanation:

The `TimerOnElapsed` method runs on a Worker Thread but to invoke the `PressCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` must be on the UI thread.

So this is the solution, the updated `TimerOnElapsed` method:

```
    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs) {
        _canExecute = !_canExecute;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(PressCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("At {0} enabled: {1}", elapsedEventArgs.SignalTime.ToLongTimeString(), _canExecute);
    }
```